# CakePHP Ajax search : Showing same data two times for pagination

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

Here ajax search working fine but the problem is same data is showing two times, because I have given pagination limit 2.If I make it 3, same result is showing 3 times.

Here is my index.ctp

```
$( "#search" ).keyup(function() {

    var value=$('#search').val();   

        $.get("<?php echo   Router::url(array('controller'=>'userTypes','action'=>'search'));?>",{search:value},function(data){
        $('.search_data').html(data);
     });
})
```

Here is my search action

```
public function search()
    {
        $search=$_GET['search'];
        $request=$this->UserType->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('UserType.name LIKE' => "%$search%")
        ));
        $this->set('usertype',$request);
    }
```

Here is the search.ctp

```
<?php foreach($usertype as $usertypes) { ?>
    <tr>
            <td><?php echo $usertypes['UserType']['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $usertypes['UserType']['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $usertypes['UserType']['description']; ?></td>

    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Pagination limit In appcontroller

```
 parent::beforeFilter();
            $this->Paginator->settings = array(
              'limit'=>2
        );
```

Result is showing me like this

[image]

May anybody help me for solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use pagination, your search method should look like this:

```
public function search()
{
    if(isset($this->request->query['search'])){
       $search = $this->request->query['search'];
    }else{
       $search = '';
    )
    $this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'conditions' => array('UserType.name LIKE' => "%$search%"),
        'limit' => 2
    );
    ));
    $this->set('usertype',$this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```